# Win 10 IoT: WindowsIoTCoreWatcher.exe does not show my Raspberry PI device

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Raspberry  PI with Win 10 IoT installed.

- The device is connected through Ethernet, I can ping it
- I've connected through Powershell, changed admin password. Followed instructions here: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm
- I can connect to the device's web based interface http://ip:8080

However, WindowsIoTCoreWatcher.exe does not show or list my device. I tried Refresh button, run as admin. Still no result.

How can I fix the issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WindowsIoTCoreWatcher listens for UDP broadcasts that are sent every five seconds by a process running on the device: C:\Windows\System32\ebootpinger.exe. It appears that this process occasionally dies or stops broadcasting, particularly if the device has not been rebooted in several days. It can be restarted with the PowerShell command (e.g. in a remote interactive session):

```bsh
Start-Process ebootpinger.exe
```

Comment: I had the same problem while doing a demo at the local Microsoft office using their public wireless access.  Someone suggested using another wireless network so I switched to a wireless network from a phone and it worked.  However, I couldn't explain why it would not work on the MS network but @perterdn answer shed a light on that...UDP being blocked could explain the problem.

Comment: @peterden This solved the problem. I appreciate if you help and tell me how did you get such deep understanding on Win 10 IoT?

Comment: @AllanXu Mainly tinkering! This problem was bugging me as well, and it involved firstly using Wireshark to identify traffic coming from the device, then isolating and confirming the culprit process using `netstat -abp UDP` :-)